# Can I ask about societal topics related to EE?

Tags: discussion

I've been looking through US census data, and I noticed that male EE majors tend to get married much earlier than other engineering majors (https://data.census.gov/mdat/#/search?ds=ACSPUMS1Y2019&vv=AGEP(25:35)&cv=SEX(1),MAR&rv=FOD1P&wt=PWGTP). Is it okay if I ask why that might be here? If not, can anyone suggest other places to ask this question, or look for more information?

Comment: If you really want proper data you need to control the sample of the population that is surveyed. You can't ask a question like that here or on reddit and expect to get a truly representative sample of EE majors. How would you even know if respondents have an EE degree?

Comment: This isn't how science works - you need to question if the study has accurate data to begin with rather than blindly trusting it to be correct then drawing strange conclusions. For example if this study only covers USA, it might be that EE is a more common degree in states with a big electronics industry. In which case the study might actually show that people in Texas get married much earlier than people in Michigan or whatever - that is, cultural differences between states in USA, which is completely unrelated to the EE degree itself, but more likely related to religion etc.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? This is the meta. Even if the answer is no, where else are you going to ask this kind of stuff but the meta?

Comment: @HAL, take this question to our [EE.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering).  Don't post it to the main EE.SE board.

Answer (score 7):

The help center advises on [What topics can I ask about here?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> questions about electrical and electronics engineering topics, which
> include electronics, physical computing, and those working with
> microcontrollers, Arduinos and embedded systems.

Furthermore, [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) states:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
> problems that you face.

Since the census question is about people, not engineering or electronics, it is off-topic here.

You can look through the list of [other sites in the Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name), but I didn't notice anything relevant to your question there.